# Google Maps Java Script API handle when no Internet Connection is there

Tags: javascript, google-maps, connection

I have integrated Google Maps in my application using their Javascript API.

I have a requirement to popup an Information Dialogue and show a static map image when there is no internet connection available, but google Map is already launched on the browser.

Does google javascript Map API provides a handle/response when i zoom or pan while it is fetching the image tiles and no internet connection available ?

Comment: How could it? No network means no new data.

Comment: The scenario is like this...Initially you have internet connection, you are able to launch google map, now you disconnect the network and then try to zoom/pan on the launched google map. At this time, it doesn't fetch the image tiles...but at this time is there a way that i can get notified programatically.

Comment: How it's possible. If internet is disconnected then how it will fetch require data.

Answer (score 0):

No,It's not possible to handle google maps javascript api without internet connection you must have active internet connection.